# When will the M1 macbooks come with only software that is completely native?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon

Has apple announced a timeframe of when the macbooks will ship with only native software for M1 chip? Currently software goes through a translation process in order for it to work on the m1 chips.

Comment: do you mean built-in softwares ? or *every* softwares that exist ?

Comment: built-in software, basically just software that ships with a new mac

Comment: AskDifferent works best with questions that have specific concrete answers. Asking questions that would involve guessing what Apple might or might not do or when they might or might not do it are officially **off topic** and will be closed as they are not based in fact but merely an opinion. And we are *all about* the facts. So if you can word it in a way that involves a concrete provable answer, I would recommend that. Otherwise you might want to take that question to a discussion board, maybe like MacRumors.com. :-)

Comment: From release M1 machines don't need to run Intel code you only run Rosetta if a third party program needs it. Your last sentence is incorrect all supplied software runs natively nad not through a translation process.

Comment: It would be useful to know where you got the information that built-in software goes through a translation process

Comment: This has an answer that explains the software is native when it ships. Perhaps you are asking hot to know this and a quick edit will fix that error. If this is about some article that explains things,can you edit that reference in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new M1 Macs ***already*** ship with only native software. MacOS Big Sur is made up of "Universal Binaries" that contain both Intel and Apple Silicon (AS) code. On an M1 Mac, the AS code is executed. On an Intel Mac, the Intel code is executed.

(In fact, the Apple Silicon code is included on Intel Macs running Big Sur.)

Plenty of third-party software is already available as Universal Binaries. Intel code is only translated when no AS code is available. And you have to download the Rosetta2 translation layer to implement it.

If you're asking when will Apple remove the translation layer, so that only AS code can run (as it did by removing Rosetta from OS X Lion): nobody knows. Or if they do, they're not telling.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that Rosetta II isn‘t installed by default so any M1 Mac runs 100% native code out of the box.